# Excel VBA - Determine if document is Trusted (vs just macros enabled for session)

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked and looked, but can someone tell me if there a VBA way, in Excel 365, to determine if the current workbook is trusted (meaning the user went into File->Options-> Trust Center and chose to "Trust the Document" instead of having simply clicking Enable Macros (for this session)?  I need to know if the workbook is "permanently" trusted, not just temporarily.

As a secondary question--if such a thing IS possible via VBA--is there a vba command (without a complicated sendkeys) to open straight to the above "Trust this Document" button when it's determined the document is NOT trusted?

Comment: no, there is no way to tell, and there is no way to bipass it.

Comment: More complicated to do that, but I can show you how to check if the workbook folder is in the Trusted Locations, which means that the workbook is a trusted document. Also how to write in Registry to add the active workbook folder in Excel Trusted Locations.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was afraid of that.  I won't be able to touch the registry for the users using this, so that's a no go, and the doc will be individually trusted, so the location won't help in this case, sadly.   Does anyone know how to at least pop open the window that gets them to the "Trust this Document" button via VBA (I'm hoping to avoid sendkeys, which always seems to go wonky once in a while for people).

Comment: So, do you need a solution, but you/the users cannot access registry? Otherwise, I can make a piece of code able to tell you if the workbook is on the trusted documents list and placing its folder in the Trusted Locations will place it on the list, too. I suppose I will be able to even place it on the list, but even if I know where the registry key to be placed, it needs a Hex time stamp which needs research and not needing such a thing, I do not have enough time even for a challenge... Anyhow, I never could see such a button ("Trust this Document"). Can you place a picture of it, please?